# Cast or convert a pointer (T*) to a two-const (T const * const) pointer

Tags: c++, casting, auto, const-correctness, const-cast

**C++**

I want to know if a pointer that isn’t already a two-`const` pointer (e.g. `T const * const`) can be implicitly or explicitly cast, processed through something (e.g. a function), or otherwise converted, to yield a `T const * const`, without or before being used to initialize a variable that is declared as a `T const * const`. How can I do this?

I thought that if I started with a `T*`, then one `const_cast` (or two, in case the cast can only cast in one `const` at a time) would suffice, but apparently it doesn’t. Many variables in the code show a different unsuccessful attempt at yielding `T const * const` through casting or returning from a function. Every cast failed to return a pointer with a trailing `const`. (I refer to the `const` to the left of `*` as the leading `const` and the one to the right of `*` as the trailing `const`.) Because of the unsuccessful casts, I tried unsuccessfully to force the `const` through direct initialization. This was compiled in `VC11`. [g++ on stack-crooked.com](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2340a94e7a8f7f3e) gives a logically equivalent console output, albeit with different names for `typeid(/*...*/).name()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int const * const foo()
{
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 7;

    auto a1 = &x;
    cout << typeid(a1).name() << endl;

    auto a2 = const_cast<int const *>(&x);
    cout << typeid(a2).name() << endl;

    auto a3 = const_cast<int * const>(&x);
    cout << typeid(a3).name() << endl;

    auto a4 = const_cast<int const * const>(&x);
    cout << typeid(a4).name() << endl;

    auto a5 = const_cast<int const * const>(a4);
    cout << typeid(a5).name() << endl;

    auto a6 = (int const * const) &x;
    cout << typeid(a6).name() << endl;

    auto a7 = static_cast<int const * const>(a4);
    cout << typeid(a7).name() << endl;

    auto a8 = reinterpret_cast<int const * const>(a4);
    cout << typeid(a8).name() << endl;

    auto a9 = foo();
    cout << typeid(a9).name() << endl;

    int const * const a10 = &x;
    cout << typeid(a10).name() << endl;
    cout << ( typeid(a10) == typeid(a4) ) << endl;

    auto a12 = a10;
    cout << typeid(a12).name() << endl;
    cout << ( typeid(a12) == typeid(a4) ) << endl;
}
```

**Expected results vs. actual results, and questions:**

Question numbers correspond to the same-numbered `a#` variables.

1. Got expected result `int *`
2. Got expected result `int const *`
3. Expected `int* const`, but got `int*`. Did the `const_cast` ignore its trailing `const` argument and why? Since the return is the same constness and type as the argument, did the cast run at all?
4. Expected `int const * const`, but got `int const*`. Did the `const_cast` ignore its trailing `const` argument and why?
5. I wanted to see if `const_cast<int const * const>` will include a trailing `const` in the result given that the argument `a4` already has a leading `const`. Expected `int const * const`. Got `int const*`. Did the `const_cast` ignore its trailing `const` argument and why?
6. Expected `int const * const`. Got `int const*`. Why would the explicit cast still exclude the trailing `const`?
7. Expected `int const * const`. Got `int const*`. Why would the `static_cast` exclude the trailing `const`?
8. Expected `int const * const`. Got `int const*`. Why would the `reinterpret_cast` exclude the trailing `const`?
9. Expected `int const * const`. Got `int const*`. Why would an initialization to the `int const * const` return of a function still exclude the trailing `const` in the result?
10. Expected `int const * const`. Got `int const*` from the console output but not from the debugger. `a10` is explicitly declared as `int const * const`, so why does the `typeid().name()` exclude the trailing const? `operator==` yields `1`, so why is the `typeid()` itself (not just the name) for `a10` equivalent to that of `a4`? The VC11 debugger lists `a10`’s type as `int const * const`. Why is it different than the one from `typeid()` and `typeid().name()`? Which one is correct?
11. variable name `a11` omitted because it looks like the word “all”.
12. I expected `a12` to be `int const * const` because it is initialized to `a10`, which was explicitly declared `int const * const`.  `operator==` yields `1`, so `typeid()` is still `int const*`. Got `int const*` from both the console output and the debugger. Why are they different from the expected result?

Are all casts, function returns, and initializations limited to only casting in one `const` at a time? Is the leading `const` the only thing they can cast in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const_cast` does work the way you think it does. However, `auto` doesn't do what you think it does. `auto` works similarly to function template parameter deduction (in fact, it's defined in terms of the latter). Now consider:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T x);

f(42);
int const n = 42;
f(n);
```

Both calls are to `f<int>()`, not `f<const int>()`. Top-level const modifiers are ignored by template parameter deduction. For the same reason, in this example

```
auto a = 42; a = 84;
auto b = n;  b = 84;
```

variables `a` and `b` are of type `int`, not `const int`, and can be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; that clarifies many issues, but do you have an answer for #10? Also, do you mean the leading `const` isn’t a top-level `const` modifier; only the trailing `const` is? Since `auto` ignores top-level const modifiers, how can I observe, preferably store, the immediate results of each cast before the top-level const modifier is lost? Can `const_cast<T const * const>(&t_type)` cast a `T*` directly to `T const * const`, or do I need two casts, one for each `const`?

Comment: **5.2.8/5** The top-level cv-qualifiers of the glvalue expression or the *type-id* that is the operand of `typeid` are always ignored.

Comment: The const that applies to the variable being declared is the top-level `const` modifier, whether it lexically appears at the beginning or at the end. In `const int n = 42` and `int const n = 42`, `const` modifiers are top-level. In `const int* const! p`, `int const * const! p`, `typedef const int* CP; const! CP p`, I marked the top-level qualifiers with an exclamation point.

Comment: Your replies have been very helpful, but do you have answers to the last two questions in my previous comment to your answer? Sorry if your answers and comments already apply. My Standardese is poor.

Comment: Why do you **want** to observe top-level `const` modifier? What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? You are trying hard to make a const rvalue - but an rvalue is, by definition, not modifiable; a const modifier on it is redundant. '5' is no more or less constant than `const_cast<const int>(5)`. You can assign either to a `const int` variable. Similarly, you can happily write `const int* const p = const_cast<const int*>(&x)`;

Comment: Goal: see what `const_cast` returns including all const qualifiers. Observation of top-level const modifier unnecessary as soon as I find out. From your answer: “const_cast does work the way you think it does.” I'd like more clarification because I don't know exactly what it returns; OP asks **if** the top-level const can be cast in and **how many** casts is needed to cast in both top- and non-top-level consts. Though OP didn’t say the pointer to cast from is an lvalue, that's what I mean.Not every cast in OP was from rvalue (e.g. `a4`).Tried to find answer from Standard but some parts dubious

Comment: Dubious parts of Standard: C++11, **5.2.11/1 [expr.const.cast]** gives `const_cast<T>(v)`, **5.2.11/3** states `T1` can be `const_cast` to `T2` if “T1 is cv1,0 pointer to cv1,1 pointer to… cv1,n  T and T2 is cv2,0 pointer to cv2,1 pointer to…pointer to cv2,n T…where cv1,k and cv2,k nay be different cv-qualifications…” **/1** appears to group cv-qualifications into `T` but `/3` does not. Even if it means I can cast `T1` to `T2` including the cv-qualifications, I’m not sure if cv-qualifiers (**3.9.3**) include both the top-level const and the non-top-level const.

Comment: **/1** simply explains the syntax of `const_cast` expression: you cast an expression of some type to a different type. **/3** and below specify how these type types must be related to each other, for the cast to be valid. In the phrase "cv1,0 pointer to cv1,1 pointer to… cv1,n T", cv1,0 is the top-level qualifier.